# Why is my clearInterval not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Lab 10</title>  

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
</head>  
<body style="background-color:lightgreen;">

    <input type="button" id="btnSetInterval" value="log every 3 seconds" ><br />
    <input type="button" id="btnCancelSetInterval" value="cancel the logging every 3 seconds"><br />
    <input type="button" id="btnSetTimeout" value="create an event to run 3 seconds from now" /><br />

    <input type="button" id="btnCancelSetTimeout" value="cancel the event that is supposed to run 3 seconds from now" />    



<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    var intervalID;

    var timeoutID;

    function setIntervalCounter() {
        var intervalID = setInterval(function() {
        console.log("Hello World");
        }, 3000)
        }

    function stopIntervalCounter() {  
        clearInterval(intervalID);
        };  
    $("#btnSetInterval").click(setIntervalCounter);
    $("#btnCancelSetInterval").click(stopIntervalCounter); 

});    

</script>

</body>
```

// When I push the first button, the counter starts, but I am not able to stop the counter.
// I hope this is the correct way to add comments, sometimes I lose my code in the view 
// I know this question is asked many times, and I have tried all solutions. :(

Comment: you are creating a new local variable `intervalID` instead of using the previous one. Remove var from function `setIntervalCounter`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are redeclaring the intervalID variable. It is scoped to the setIntervalCounter() function. Remove the var. Like this:

```
 function setIntervalCounter() {
        intervalID = setInterval(function() {
        console.log("Hello World");
        }, 3000)
        }
```

Comment: :(  Thanks, I was looking for errors in all the wrong places.  It works great now.  :)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the word `var` from the line where you set the interval.  That's making a new local variable, not using the global one.

Comment: Thanks,  I was looking for errors in the wrong places.  You both were fast to answer, and I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

```
function setIntervalCounter() {
    intervalID = setInterval(function() {
    console.log("Hello World");
    }, 3000)
    }
```

This is the correct one

Answer (score 0):

```
var intervalID = setInterval(function() {
    console.log("Hello World");
    }, 3000)
   }
```

intervalID is defined as LOCAL variable of the function setIntervalCounter.

Therefore, you should delete the "var" before intervalID, since intervalID is already declared as a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's because the interval ID you've defined inside the setIntervalCounter() function is scoped to that function only.

If you define a variable in JavaScript using the 'var' keyword inside a function, that variable will be scoped to that function only - meaning you can't access it from outside the function.

Your "stopIntervalCounter()" method is operating against the global 'intervalID' variable (the one you defined in the first line of the document.ready), which is why your interval is not being cleared.

Try removing the var from the setIntervalCounter method - that should mean it'll be assigning the value to the correct instance of intervalID.